Chain Normal Work with Unique Work using WorkManager
Can we achieve a work chain where first work is normal work and second one is unique work. Something like this:
val saveToPendingList = OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(SavePendingListWorker::class.java)
    .build()

val constraints = Constraints.Builder()
    .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
    .build()

val firebaseUpload = OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(FirebaseUploadWorker::class.java)
    .setConstraints(constraints)
    .build()

// Chain the work requests: saveToPendingList -> firebaseUpload (unique)
WorkManager.getInstance(context)
    .beginWith(saveToPendingList)
    .then(
        WorkManager.getInstance(context)
            .beginUniqueWork(uniqueWorkName, ExistingWorkPolicy.KEEP, firebaseUpload)
    )
    .enqueue()

First work should always run even if there's one or more instances of same worker running. But in case of second work, if one instance already in pending or running then do not enqueue new one, keep the old one.
In short there should be only one instance of firebaseUpload work at a time.
